# AWS WAF - Auto Save Web Application Firewall logs in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How do you route AWS Web Application Firewall (WAF) logs to an S3 bucket? Is this something I can quickly do through the AWS Console? Or, would I have to use a lambda function (invoked by a CloudWatch timer event) to query the WAF logs every n minutes?

**UPDATE**: 
I'm interested in the ACL logs (Source IP, URI, Matches rule, Request Headers, Action, Time, etc).

**UPDATE (05/15/2017)**
AWS doesn't provide an easy way to view/parse these logs. You can get a "random sample" via the get-sampled-requests command. Which isn't acceptable...

> Gets detailed information about a specified number of requests--a
>   sample--that AWS WAF randomly selects from among the first 5,000
>   requests that your AWS resource received during a time range that you
>   choose. You can specify a sample size of up to 500 requests, and you
>   can specify any time range in the previous three hours.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/waf/get-sampled-requests.html

Also, I'm not the only one experiencing this issue either:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=220202

Comment: Any service that alters or denies your customer traffic should provide you with a comprehensive audit log. It's a shame they don't support this yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this functionality today and stumbled across the referenced thread. It was, coincidentally, updated today:

> Hello,
>
> Thanks for your input. I have submitted a feature request on your
>   behalf to export WAF events to S3 for long term analysis.
>
> Best Regards, albertpataws

The lack of this feature strikes me as being almost as odd as the fact that I can't change timezones for graphs.